# Node.js memory goes up slowly, but it falls to normal when stopping sending request

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, express, jmeter

I have Node.js(v0.10.26) + Express.js as my web server, which hosts a website and it serves:

1. Hosting for all resources (both static and non-static ones)
2. Responding for HTTP requests to get a dynamic page
3. Restful APIs

I am using jade as template.

I am using node-mysql to read/write db data.

I am running nodejs on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine.

---

When I started to run performance test with Apache JMeter with 5 concurrent clients (100 seconds to head-up), I found that:

1. The one CPU core for the nodejs instance goes up to almost 100%, and always keeps 100%.
2. The memory usage for nodejs instance started with about 90MB, and **goes up slowly with about 10MB per day**.
3. When I stopped the JMeter from sending requests, the memory usage went down quickly to normal status: about 90MB.
4. The requests count per seconds continues to go down, at the beginning I have about 12 requests per second, but it falls to 8 requests per second after 2 days running.

and during the performance test, there is no error occurs.

My question is:

1. Why the node.js instance memory goes up slowly? I am supposing it to goes up for a while and keep stable at a level.
2. If there is any memory leak, why the memory goes down after shutting down the JMeter?
3. Why the requests count per second falls?

Comment: This issue is not related to Jmeter. You need to review your Infra setup

Comment: what do you mean of "Infra setup"?

Comment: Server: CPU, Memory, IO, Swap Usage, etc..      Also are you running Jmeter and Node.js on same machine.

Comment: yes, they are on the same machine, I have tried another test with jmeter and node.js on the different machine, but have the same problem.

Comment: I have no exact information of swap usage, but I am sure that server CPU and memory keep in good level.

Comment: You should always keep Jmeter and Node.js on separate machines.    Also please share the details of CPU and Memory capacity of Node.js machine & Jmeter machine.

Comment: Also since you have mentioned that "memory goes up slowly, but it falls to normal when stopping sending request", it is a normal behavior. That means that your application is consuming high CPU & Memory under load.  when you stop the test ... it releases the memory and goes back to normal

Comment: In case of Memory Leak, release of memory will not happen immediately. So in this case no memory leak.

Comment: Why the requests count per second falls? This happens because, Jmeter machine has consumed lot of memory & CPU. Jmeter itself needs load of Memory and CPU to generate load, in your case for 2 days.  So keep Jmeter & Node.js on separate machine and constantly monitor the CPU & Memory usage on both machines.

Comment: thanks very much! I will try to separate nodejs and JMeter and test again.